# Allowing user to edit account without the :id param in the url

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I'd like to accomplish having a URL that's

```
users/edit
```

instead of the current

```
users/7/edit
```

I have my own auth system built upon omniauth. Thus I store their user_id in a session. How would I go about accomplishing this task?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming that you use `current_user`, even if you are using something else just replace `current_user` with your method, I am using `current_user` here, follow these steps,

1. Create an action, I would name it `edit_user` in your users controller

   ```
   def edit_user
     @user = current_user # or User.find(session[:user_id])
   end
   ```
2. Add routes to `routes.rb`

   ```
   get "/users/edit" => "users#edit_user"
   ```

You are done, you can use the above route anywhere in the application, you can also name the route if needed.

**OR**, if you don't want to define a new action and want to use the existing `edit` action, do this

1. Remove routes for `edit` from the default `resources` routes and then manually define it. In this way, you can use the existing `edit` action

   ```
   resources :users, except: [:edit]
   get "/users/edit" => "users#edit"
   ```

Hope this helped!